# Keystone.js: use one model in multiple sites

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

I need to create multiple sites using Keystone.js (sites network). I have a reference collection, which should be used on every site as a relationship to models in other network's sites. It's like universal tags list used across all network's site. Hope you understand what I mean. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without really understanding your use case i see two potential architectures to explore:

1. Single keystone instance:

   See if you can design your data to use inheritance and try putting
   all sites in one keystone instance. IE you could have a parent
   "Post" model and then a per site "FooPost", "BarPost" that inherits
   from post. This way you could use the stock keystone/mongoose
   relationship mechanisms and built-in CRUD bootstraps. Drawback here
   is this architecture will make your admin UI and data model more
   complicated but i think its a potential solution to "partitioning" a
   single keystone instance into separate sites. This might work better
   for just a few "sites" on one instance as more then that would just
   make the data model and admin UX too complicated to use.

   Pros: can use keystone stock CRUD/relationships

   Cons: more complicated admin UX, you'll have to manually partition the front    end out yourself to keep the data separate, more complicated data structure using a lot of inheritance
2. separate keystone instances:

   a lightweight way to share non-relational data between separate keystone instances  (like a common tag list) could be to just bootstrap an api wrapper to a "tag" model for each site and add api CRUD calls to each keystone instance API . Then you could maintain the model data across sites by calling the CRUD api via mongoose hooks. There are plenty of examples out there to boostrap keystone CRUD api and you could just make an api CRUD call within the model's post save, post delete, or post update.

   To model relationships would be more complicated. I would create a "Link" model on each site that was nothing more then a URL field and an _id. Set up a one to many relationship in the models on each site you are trying to share relationships with and wrap the Link model in a CRUD api. This way you could "link" the models together and they would render out as clickable links on the admin pages. You would have to code a pretty fair amount of hook and API calls but i think this is a potentially feasible architecture for a system that can allow for some transactional data sync tolerance (IE you wouldnt try this type of architecture for anything that requires super tight transactional integrity but its probably ok for social media).

   Pros: separation of concerns, cleaner data model, partitioned admin screens (maybe a con for some use cases)

   Cons: need to sync data model schema (you can submodule a common keystone models github repo and share it between all sites to fix this problem ive done that before), more api and schema hook code, each site has a separate admin UX, more sysadmin work to run and sync separate instances

Comment: In a multi tenant scenario sir , what would be the best advice you can give ? based on the two choices you have explianed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible per-se, however if it's a reference collection then why not just run it on it's own site, and have all the other sites query that one for data?

I tried running two sites in the same instance once. It causes all models with the same names to share a collection in the database, which is not a good thing to be doing really as it means the `updates` collection that keystone creates will be shared between apps, and also any users (unless you call the users model something different on each site). It's certainly not designed to cope with this.